# Angular httpClient: mapping response to model without losing non-specified properties

Tags: angular, typescript, model

Suppose I have the class

```
export class DummyClass {
   name: string;
   value: number = 10;
}
```

So a class that holds only `name` and `value` with a default value of 10.

If I now want to get data from the server and I initiate my call.

```
this.httpClient.post<DummyClass>(...)
```

And the json response is

```
{
   "name": "john doe"
}
```

Then my class also looks like this. This implies I have complete lost my property `value` with its default value as wel. And this was the whole point of my default value -> such that the server does not need to send default values.

How can I correctly map the json response to a model and not lose default values.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when you fetch data from an API, you don't get a class instance. You get a plain object.

This means that your API response **follows** the class interface, but does not *instanciate* it.

There might be some libraries around to do that, haven't checked.

To resolve your issue, you can use a pipe in your API call :

```js
this.http.post<DummyClass>(...).pipe(
  map(res => {
    const instance = new DummyClass();
    Object.assign(instance, res);
    return instance;
  })
);
```

There a LOTS of ways to do it, with each having their pros and cons, but this one is the most broad and simple one I think.

Comment: I have been thinking about that solution as well (to pipe-map them) but the problem with this is with nesting. if the class with default value isn't the root object but some child object of the root object than this `Object.assign` solution wont work either.

Comment: That's why I said there is multiple solutions to it. I found a library that could do it for you : https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer